# Error: Failed to transpile program Ionic 3

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am getting an error when I try to run `ionic cordova run android`:

> Error: Failed to transpile program
>
> at new BuildError
>   (/home/sevenbits/sevenbits-git/androidapplications/IonicBlockchainApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
>
> at /home/sevenbits/sevenbits-git/androidapplications/IonicBlockchainApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:159:20
>
> at new Promise ()
>
> at transpileWorker (/home/sevenbits/sevenbits-git/androidapplications/IonicBlockchainApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:107:12)
>
> at Object.transpile (/home/sevenbits/sevenbits-git/androidapplications/IonicBlockchainApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:64:12)
>
> at /home/sevenbits/sevenbits-git/androidapplications/IonicBlockchainApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:109:82
>
> ```
> at <anonymous>
> ```

I really don't know where the error came from. How can I fix it?

Comment: try using `ionic doctor check` maybe it will show the direct issue in project

Comment: @siddhantsankhe i tried that command. it  detected 0 issues.

Comment: @Riddhi can u check whether android is installed properly as well as the permissions are given as well can u confirm whether r u using any local forage

Comment: @Riddhi try to reinstall the node again

Comment: @Riddhi check your typescript version, in my latest project version is  `"typescript": "~2.6.2"` and `@ionic/app-scripts` to latest version

Comment: @siddhantsankhe I found `"typescript": "~2.6.2"` in my package.json

Comment: @Nidhinkumar can you provide steps for reinstalling the node?

Comment: Thanks @Nidhinkumar by deleting node_modules and then again using `npm install` . I reinstalled the node and now everything works fine. :)

Answer (score 3):

I updated typescript by typing npm install typescript@2.7.2 and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to lock `ionic/app-scripts` to v3.2.3, also you can use `ionic doctor check` if any other issue.